# Can't install mysql on ubuntu 12.04, Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Trying to install mysql, using apt-get but it fails

```
# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,726 kB of archives.
After this operation, 31.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mysql-server-5.5 i386 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [8,714 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mysql-server all 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [11.7 kB]
Fetched 8,726 kB in 12s (686 kB/s)                                             
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 30953 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
egrep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
120810 17:25:06 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
120810 17:25:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120810 17:25:06 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120810 17:25:06  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120810 17:25:07 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120810 17:25:07 [ERROR] Aborting

120810 17:25:07  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120810 17:25:07  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
120810 17:25:07 [Note] 
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea what's wrong?

[Update]
It was due to bad template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this could be caused by several different things, file/directory permission is one, mysql version/OS mismatch, or just package bug. it is hard to tell which ones you are hitting. you can alternative try to use the packages directly from mysql download or percona which are often easier to install.

if you can locate this binary, try to run the following:

mysql_install_db --user=mysql --no-defaults

this may fix things. otherwise, try to bring your OS up to date, purge the mysql packages, and install again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran apt-get install mysql-server command on my freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 x86-64 server and mysql-server installed successfully.

Looks like your Ubuntu installation has issues. I'd recommend a re-install or try installing mysql from source.

Answer (score 0):

Purge mysql-common and try to install again mysql-server:

```
apt-get purge mysql-common
apt-get install mysql-server
```